# Simple Way To Retrieve a table using an API from MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, api, ssis, wsdl

I'm a rookie with API's so please be gentle.

I have a snippet of code i found online that I want to use to to retrieve data into a table on my SQL Server 2019.

When I run this it returns nothing, Yet if i paste the API URL into my browser it returns data.

This server does not appear to offer "WSDL" for me to use Integration Services.

How can i get this to work?  The [documentation](https://www.nzbplanet.net/apihelp) isn't all that helpful to get this going in SQL.

```
Declare @Object as Int;
Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000);

--Code Snippet
Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get',
                 'https://api.nzbplanet.net/api?&t=search&q=wing&apikey={{myapikey}}', --Your Web Service Url (invoked)
                 'false'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT

Select @ResponseText

Exec sp_OADestroy @Object
```

Comment: Why are you doing this from within SQL Server, and not an application server of some kind? Just because you _can_ do this doesn't mean that you _should_.

Comment: I don't have an application server.

Comment: You must have another server running _somewhere_ - you aren't running your entire system on a single system, are you?

Comment: i have other servers but no application servers.  Why can't i do it entirely in SQL or Intergrated services?

Comment: Because - and this should be obvious - there is no native tsql support for doing this. You are using the creaky, rotten, fragile, error-prone, and difficult to code/debug OLE automation procedures. Refer to comments in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60918783/making-a-api-call-from-with-authentication-from-sql-trigger).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an SSIS script component to retrieve the payload of an API and write the results to an output buffer. Then write the results into SSIS.  I would avoid connecting a database directly to the internet for security considerations.

Below is an example:

1) This uses the webclient class to connect to the api.  In this cases a token was uses to authorize the connection (authToken).  Also it is using TLS 1.2 which might not be required for your connection

2) Uri is stored in a variable in ssis and then specified as a readonly variable in the scriptcomponent

3) The DownloadString() method downloads a json payload in this case.  Newtonsoft.Json is used to deserialize the json.  The json is also defined below as classes so it can be parsed into a .NET object

4) The outputbuffer columns are defined in the script component.  We loop through each value in the data class and set the values for each row.

5) The last step is just mapping this script component source to an oledb destination for the sql database.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{

    public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
    {
        var uri = Variables.Uri;
        string authToken = Variables.authToken;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");
            client.Headers.Add("authToken", authToken);
            var response = client.DownloadString(uri);
            json parsedResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<json>(response);
            foreach (var value in parsedResponse.data.values)
            {
                Output0Buffer.AddRow();
                Output0Buffer.CreatedBy = value.CreatedBy;
                Output0Buffer.CreatedOn = value.CreatedOn;
            }
        }
    }
}
public class json
{
    public status responseStatus { get; set; }
    public data data { get; set; }
}

public class data
{
    public List<values> values { get; set; }
}

public class values
{

    public string CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem too simple.  Not sure where to put the variable and how it integrates to the script.  I've never done this before.

Comment: This is an intermediate level solution.  For what I’ve given here, you’ll have a little to change and figure out. Taking this on will definitely advance your skills in SSIS.  I would suggest spending some time looking at other examples of script components to get the hang of working with output buffers and variables.

Comment: I spent an hour or so looking at this. I really want to try and use it.  If you know any good overview videos or websites on some of the underlying techniques that would be great.

Comment: I couldn't recommend any videos, but this link seems to touch all the key elements: https://www.sqlshack.com/ssis-script-component-overview/  This assumes you have the basics down and understand the difference between sync / async components, etc.  I suggest taking this a piece at a time, to learn each part - maybe start by creating one row with dummy values and work on each piece from there

Comment: Still working on this. Having a weird problem where i install JSON into the script package and it looks good. Then i save all and go back to the ssis data flow. If i return to the script the  "Using Newtonsoft.Json;" line shows that the namespace is no longer there.

Yet packages.config shows it's installed.  No errors during install.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="12.0.1" targetFramework="net47" />
</packages>

Comment: Did you add newtonsoft to the gac?